Which cache is triggered in the spring booth application when changing the base url for the WebClient?
In file
spring:
profiles:
active: dev
application:
name: user-service
jpa:
hibernate:
ddl-auto: validate
show-sql: true
properties:
hibernate:
format_sql: true
default_schema: security
open-in-view: false
liquibase:
enabled: true
change-log: liquibase/db.changelog-master.yml
default-schema: security
security:
jwt:
secret: ${SECRET_KEY:73357638792F423F4528482B4D6251655468576D5A7133743677397A24432646}
access: ${TIME_ACCESS_TOKEN:1}
refresh: ${TIME_REFRESH_TOKEN:2}
server:
port: ${SERVER_PORT:8081}
urls:
emailservice_url: http://email-service:8088/
I can comment out the emailservice_url line, but the application can be left and run a few more times. How does the cache work here?
I was a debager, but I didn't understand anyway.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
